# Local SEO | Repetitive use of City Name on-page in H tags

Tags: content, local-seo, ux

We are getting advice from an SEO professional that for our local not for profit site offering arts programming to perform well in local SEO we need to liberally use our City name in H1 or H2 tags on-page.

This has opened up a UX and Content Strategy debate as the continual repetition of [Program Name in City Name] feels incredibly repetitive and inauthentic for a user as they browse the site in terms of content experience in navigation, on landing pages, etc. You see our city name a million times while clicking around.

Does anyone have insight? How do you strike the balance between SEO keyword strategies and quality, authentic content experiences for human users?

Comment: I don't have a lot of experience with *local* SEO, but keyword stuffing like that has been really bad for Google web search rankings in the last few years.

Comment: This sounds like idiot SEO advice. I would have fired the fool on the spot. I do almost no local SEO, however, the signals are not repeating crap in header tags. How about NAP (name, address, phone) on a contact page, schema mark-up, Google maps, Google My Business, and so on. We do have really good local SEO answers here including some I wrote if you need expert advice. Cheers!!

Answer (score 1):

Your intention should be built best content for the user and excessive repeat is definitely not good.

Repeating of location in heading tags will almost have no impact on your local ranking. Your excessive repeat may have a negative impact on your organic ranking depending or level of repeat.

Now, you need to give the signal to search engine about local service so you can have the location in the heading or description few times in some key pages but don't over do it.

UX: If having a location in heading will be an issue then you can have in the description etc.

**How many times repeat is good?**

- It will depend on the amount of content you may have on the page.
- Its OK to use one time in one of the heading tag.
- Roughly, if you got a content about 600 - 700 words, repeating location 2 -3 times should be fine. You can keep one in one of the heading tag and another 1 or 2 in the description.

**Conclusion:** Don't over do it. Repeat has no impact on local ranking. Create good user experience with appropriate text.

Comment: It is worth mentioning some or all of the signals that are required for Local SEO. You could also simply link to one or more good answers here. Cheers Mate!!